# Django Order QuerySet based on ManyToManyField value

Tags: django, manytomanyfield

I have a business model as follows:

```
class Business(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Businesses"

    name = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=False, verbose_name="Title")
    about = models.TextField(max_length=5000, null=True, verbose_name="Description", blank=True)
    upvote = models.ManyToManyField(Account, verbose_name="Upvote Count", blank=True)
```

The Account model is as follows:

```
class Account(models.Model):

    CHOICES = [('Male', 'Male'),Female', 'Female'),]

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Accounts"

    name = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=False, verbose_name="Title")
    gender= models.CharField(max_length=6, null=True, verbose_name="Gender", choices=CHOICES)
```

I am trying to get a QuerySet that will be sorted by gender of the Account.

How do I achieve this?

So far I have achieved sorting by the upvote count.

```
Business.objects.all().order_by("upvote")
```

Comment: This is a bit confusing, you want to sort by the field `gender` of a m2m related model? But there can be various different `gender` for the same business but different account, so how would this sorting work then?

Comment: I want to show businesses most upvoted by females/males.

Comment: It would be good to update your question to reflect what you want to achieve more clearly, in particular this part: "I am trying to get a QuerySet that will be sorted by gender of the Account." I think the answer by Abdul Aziz Barkat should do the job, given that you want to have a vote majority condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`Sum` function [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#sum) with a [Conditional Expression [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/conditional-expressions/) to annotate a value according to which you would order:

```
from django.db.models import Case, Sum, Value, When

Business.objects.annotate(
    order_value=Sum(
        Case(
            When(upvote__gender='Male', then=Value(1)),
            When(upvote__gender='Female', then=Value(-1)),
            default=Value(0)
        )
    )
).order_by('order_value')
```

The above query would give you `Business` objects with more upvotes by females first and males later, you can reverse the order by writing `.order_by('-order_value')` instead.

Comment: Thank you. Also for the documentation links. This was an interesting query.

Answer (score 0):

You can access fiels of related models by double underscore. See documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#order-by).

Try:

```
Business.objects.all().order_by("upvote__gender")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

What if I want it sorted by gender="Female"?

Comment: @DjangoEnthu What do you mean by sorted by gender = 'Female'? Oder female first, then male? Or filter results for female gender only?

Comment: Say, There are 10 business objects, and 6 objects are where it is upvoted mostly by males and 5 objects are where it is upvoted mostly by females.

I want to sort the queryset by the businesses upvoted mostly by males/females